# Error when the code is converted to runtime jar while using java reflection

Tags: eclipse, debugging, reflection

When I run my code in Eclipse, it runs smoothly. When I run it as a runnable jar file I get the following error. The code reads a string and performs a certain action if a particular substring is parsed. No external libraries are used to do this. The code runs perfectly when run on Eclipse.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unrecognised token /
        at soft.globulation.proteinParser$SubParser.parse(proteinParser.java:82)
        at soft.globulation.proteinParser.getproteinFromString(proteinParser.java:61)
        at asimov.players.iravan.donkey.RobustDynamicoptimization.getConstantprotein(RobustDynamicoptimization.java:242)
        at asimov.players.iravan.donkey.RobustDynamicoptimization.setup(RobustDynamicoptimization.java:97)
        at bio.globulator.setup(globulator.java:80)
        at bio.simple.Simpleglobulator.setup(Simpleglobulator.java:65)
        at bio.glabulutionState.setup(glabulutionState.java:391)
        at bio.simple.SimpleglabulutionState.startFresh(SimpleglabulutionState.java:49)
        at bio.glabulutionState.run(glabulutionState.java:438)
        at bio.glabulve.main(glabulve.java:769)
```

Comment: We can only tell you that the `proteinParser$SubParser` is trying to parse something and encounters an unrecognized token `/`

Comment: @Nick it works fine when compiled within eclipse. The whole code is 69 mb. Don't know which part to put here.

Comment: By the way, this part with token has no error as I wrote the code and not wrongly calling some library.

Comment: Can you print out the string that the `proteinParser$SubParser` is trying to parse?